# Is there any better way or importing mixins in vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, mixins

I have many mixins created in my project and right now what i do is i will import all the mixins in `mixins/index.js` files and in any components or pages wherever required i'll just import those mixins from `mixins/index.js`.

Now i doubt if doing show will i import all the unwanted mixins as well or will just import the mixins files i use?

Let's say i have these mixims created and imported in `mixins/index.js`

```
import a from 'mixins/a.js'
import b from 'mixins/b.js'
import c from 'mixins/c.js'
import d from 'mixins/d.js'
import e from 'mixins/e.js'

export {
  a,
  b,
  c,
  d,
  e
}
```

Now lets say in my `'x' components` i will import `'a' mixins`.

```
import { a } from 'mixins/index.js'

export default {
  mixins: [a]
}
```

In this case i only need `'a' mixins` in my `'x' components` but since i'm importing from `mixins/index.js` where i have all static imports of all mixins will this load unwanted mixins as well?

Comment: The answer, is it depends on the setup. It shouldn't load unused mixins, but it can.

Comment: @EstusFlask Can you explain a bit in what cases it can load all unwanted mixins as well? and what setup of such can cause this to happen?
Right now i'm working on nuxt js and all the config is default setup there is nothing special done in the setup.

Comment: It depends on Webpack setup that Nuxt uses internally then. I'd expect it to be ok but this isn't something that is guaranteed. The thing that affects this is called tree shaking. If it goes wrong, unused things end up in the bundle. Tree shaking usually only happens in prod builds so you can expect dev builds to be big for several reasons including this one.

Comment: Got it Thank you for sharing the infomration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`import { a } from './mixins'` will import only the requested module but if you do :

```
import * as mixins from './mixins'
```

then

```
mixins:[mixins.a]
```

this will import all the modules as explained [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import#import_an_entire_modules_contents)

Comment: Sorry i think i made a bit mistake in my code snipped it should be import from 'mixins/index.js' not 'minxins/a.js'

Comment: I fixed that and also you should have a path like `./mixins` or `../mixins`

Comment: So it means i can use the way i mentioned right? use import in mixins/index.js and only use the mixins i required in a component and in that case it will only load the mixins that is required to be used right?

Comment: Yes you're right `import {moduleName} from 'mixins/index.js'` will load only the imported module

Comment: `import * as mixins` will import only ones in use, it doesn't differ from `import { a }` in a way it works, at least if tree shaking works ok and `mixins` object isn't used directly.

Answer (score 1):

You con do something like this, import all the minmins files and than export your minmin files in the index, like this:

*index.js*

```
import a from '../mixins/a.js'
import b from '../mixins/b.js'
import c from '../mixins/c.js'
import d from '../mixins/d.js'
import e from '../mixins/e.js'

export {a, b, c, d, e}
```

then in your component, you can import a specific module exported in the index in this way:

*x component*

```
import {a, b} from "../mixins"
```

in this way you import only what you need and not all the `index.js` modules